# Choose a random string from a list as many times as a length of a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, random

Code:

```
if Dash == 0:
    # Enter X multiple times
    print("Only use X")
    Code0 = input()
    print(secrets.choice(LetterNumbers) * len(Code0))
```

The variable "LetterNumbers" is a list that contains all english letters and numbers.
Everything works, except this:

```
print(secrets.choice(LetterNumbers) * len(Code0))
```

It chooses a random letter or number from "LetterNumbers" should do that as many times as the length of the variable "Code0", but it only chooses one (for example A) and then it prints the same one just as many times as the length of "Code0".

The output is :

AAA

But it should be:

ABC (or anything random but not the same Letter everytime)

I hope you can understand what I am trying to say, because I don't speak english very well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you may get better (if at all) answers if you try to work out [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print(''.join(secrets.choice(LetterNumbers) for _ in Code0))
```

The loop variable is not something that we care about directly, so using `_` as the variable name to indicate that it is a dummy variable.

Comment: @Sen0a See also the variant which someone else posted moments later. In my code I am looping over the characters in `Code0`; in theirs they are looping over numbers from `0` to `len(Code0)-1`. It makes no difference because in both cases we are ignoring the values of the loop variable.

Comment: Ah, the other answer has since been edited, and both now say the same. What I am referring to is `for _ in range(len(Code0))` in place of `for _ in Code0`. Either will work here.

Comment: @alaniwi your solution of `_ in Code0` is more efficient. I originally derived my answer from OPs code, hence the `range(len(Code0))`.

Comment: @Nick I did wonder briefly about strings containing multi-byte Unicode characters, but it seems that although there is a difference between python 2 and python 3, in each case `len` still agrees with the number of times that you can iterate over it.

Comment: @alaniwi it's good to know that. I'd upvote you again for making the effort to check if I could...

Answer (score 1):

It prints the same letter 3 times because that's what you tell it to do with:

```
secrets.choice(LetterNumbers) * len(Code0)
```

Which produces `len(Code0)` copies of the result from a **single** call to `secrets.choice`. What you need to do is call `secrets.choice` that many times instead which you can do with a generator comprehension e.g.

```
''.join(secrets.choice(LetterNumbers) for _ in Code0)
```

Comment: I think `for _ in seq` is preferable over `for _ in range(len(seq))` given that you disregard the value anyway.

Comment: @norok2 you are correct. I was working from OPs original code which used `len(Code0)` and didn't really think enough... I've edited.

Comment: Technically this is a generator comprehension but the description currently says list comprehension. (If you omit the outer brackets but put it as a function argument then `(...)` is assumed, rather than `[...]`.)